# How to redirect user to specific page based on the input password

Tags: redirect, login, password

I would like to ask if anyone has a ready solution for WP or recommend a plugin for password-based pages, namely:

**I create:**

a) subpage 1 and a password for it, e.g. 1234

b) subpage 2 and a password for it, e.g. 4321

c) etc ...

I want to put a field on the main page "**Enter password and you will be redirected to your subpage**"

Depending on which password you enter on the main page, you will be redirected to the subpage to which the password is assigned.

I was looking for solutions but based mainly on creating accounts etc. I don't need accounts, just a simple password -> redirect to subpage.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean like a personal page?

Comment: No, I want it to work on a similar principle to the "Smart Passworded Pages Plugin".

I know how to password protect pages / posts in Worpdress.

I need to add a form on the main page where he will enter a password and take me to the given page / post